# How to filter out Eventual success records in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to filter users for my SQL Report who are not able to login within a 24 hour time period.

**TRANSACTION TABLE**

```
 USER_ID    STATUS     ENTRY_TIMESTAMP       USER_NAME
 1          SUCCESS    2019-01-15T09:29:48   Alpha
 2          FAIL       2019-01-15T09:30:48   Bravo
 3          FAIL       2019-01-15T09:31:48   Charlie
 2          SUCCESS    2019-01-15T09:32:48   Bravo
 4          FAIL       2019-01-15T09:42:48   Delta
```

**Expected Result**

```
USER_ID      STATUS    ENTRY_TIMESTAMP       USER_NAME
 3           FAIL      2019-01-15T09:31:48   Charlie
 4           FAIL      2019-01-15T09:42:48   Delta
```

Note: USER_NAME **Bravo** failed to login in first attempt **@9:30:48** but was able to login **@9:32:48**, so we don't have to put him in failed users login report

Comment: if someone fails multiple times, which timestamp are you after?

Comment: Also, is it the LAST 24 hours, or any given 24 hours?

Comment: And also, what if a user logs in successfully, but AFTER that they have a failed attempt? Also: do you need to show all the failed attempts, or just the most recent one? And, what is your Oracle version? Different (better, more efficient) solutions may exist in more recent versions, for example in 12.1 and higher.

Comment: the version of oracle i am using is PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0.

Comment: i am only interested in the user who was not able to succeed and failed consistently. (i am okay with  any timestamp). Also i am interested in 24 hours period so between Jan-15th 00:00:00 to Jan 15th 11:59:59

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where t.status = 'FAIL' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from transactions t
                  where t2.user_id = t.user_id and
                        t2.status = 'SUCCESS' and
                        t2.timestamp > t.timestamp and
                        t2.timestamp < t.timestamp + interval '1' day
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how this could be done in Oracle 12.1 and higher. For each user, it will pick up one or more rows with `status = 'FAIL'`, as long as they are within the past 24 hours and they are not followed by a row *for the same user* with `status = 'SUCCESS'`.

The `WITH` clause is there to simulate your table - it is not part of the solution (remove it, and in the main query use your actual table and column names). I am running this query at 17:41 on 2019-01-25; to make the results meaningful, I changed the date in your sample (from January 15 to January 25).

```
with
  transaction (user_id, status, entry_timestamp, user_name) as (
    select 1, 'SUCCESS', '2019-01-25T09:29:48', 'Alpha'   from dual union all
    select 2, 'FAIL'   , '2019-01-25T09:30:48', 'Bravo'   from dual union all
    select 3, 'FAIL'   , '2019-01-25T09:31:48', 'Charlie' from dual union all
    select 2, 'SUCCESS', '2019-01-25T09:32:48', 'Bravo'   from dual union all
    select 4, 'FAIL'   , '2019-01-25T09:42:48', 'Delta'   from dual
  )
select *
from   transaction
match_recognize(
  partition by user_id
  order by entry_timestamp
  all rows per match
  pattern  (a+ $)
  define   a  as entry_timestamp >= to_char(sysdate - 1, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss')
             and status = 'FAIL'
);

USER_ID ENTRY_TIMESTAMP     STATUS USER_NAME
------- ------------------- ------ ---------
      3 2019-01-25T09:31:48 FAIL   Charlie
      4 2019-01-25T09:42:48 FAIL   Delta
```

Since your timestamps show the `T` I assume they are saved as strings. That is a very poor practice; they should be stored in `date` data type.